# Is there a way to put a different time interval for each slide in react-responsive-carousal?

Tags: reactjs

**Problem:**

I have created a react-responsive-carousal. Its code is like this.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel";

class Slider extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(this.reload, 900000);
  }

  reload = () => {
    window.location.reload(true);
  };

  render() {
    const { height } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <Carousel
          autoPlay={true}
          showArrows={false}
          infiniteLoop={true}
          interval={120000}
          stopOnHover={false}
          showThumbs={false}
          showStatus={false}
          showIndicators={false}
        >
          <div>
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569_960_720.jpg"></img>
          </div>
          <div>
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569_960_720.jpg"></img>
          </div>
          <div>
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569_960_720.jpg"></img>
          </div>
        </Carousel>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Slider;
```

Can someone say is there a way to put a different time interval for each slide?. I search lot to find out whether there is a way to do it but I was unbaled to find a any clue to determine whether it can be done or cant be. So if someone can assist me with this it is really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Carousal`'s `onChange` provides you an index and the item node. So do the following.

- set a custom attribute to each carousal div say `data-interval`.
- maintain a local state to control the interval of auto-play
- update the local state upon `onChange` based on which image/div the carousal is playing.

See [working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/carousel-interval-issue-snr82)

**Code Snippet**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel";

export default () => {
  const [intervalz, setIntervalz] = useState(3000); //initial state here represents the interval for first image.

  const onChange = (index, item) => {
    setIntervalz(item.props["data-interval"]);
  };
  return (
    <Carousel
      onChange={onChange}
      autoPlay
      interval={intervalz}
      infiniteLoop={true}
    >
      <div data-interval={3000}>
        <img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-1.jpg" />
        <p className="legend">Legend 1</p>
      </div>
      <div data-interval={5000}>
        <img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-2.jpg" />
        <p className="legend">Legend 2</p>
      </div>
      <div data-interval={1000}>
        <img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-3.jpg" />
        <p className="legend">Legend 3</p>
      </div>
    </Carousel>
  );
};
```